# Asp.Net Core MVC ajax partialview render doesnt empty table when result empty

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

I have a page with a partial view '_PartialList'. Code:

```html
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
        <div class="card" id="listHeader">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h5 class="card-title">Seznam kontaktov</h5>
                <label id="lbTest">test</label>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 form-inline">
                        <select id="ddlSelect" asp-items="Model.Stranke" onchange="filterData();" class="form-control"></select>

                        <input type="text" name="SearchString" placeholder="Išči" value="@ViewData[" CurrentFilter"]" id="tbSearch" class="form-control" />

                        <input value="Išči" type="button" id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-primary ml-2" onclick="filterData();" />

                        <div class="text-right">
                            <a asp-controller="Kontakti" asp-action="Add" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Dodaj</a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="sectionList">
                @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_PartialList", Model);}
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

In the partialview I have a table that displays all the records I return from the controller. Users can filter the data via the @ddlSelect and @tbSearch. For this I use the below jquery:

```
function filterData() {

            var sender = $(this).attr('id');

            // drop down
            var strSelected = "";
            $('#ddlSelect option:selected').each(function () {
                strSelected += $('#ddlSelect')[0].value;
            });

            // search text
            var search = $('#tbSearch').val();

            // url 
            var url = '/Kontakti/IndexPartial?idSelect=' + strSelected;
            url += '&searchString=' + search;

            // partial reload
            $('#sectionList').load(url);

            return false;
        }
```

This works great when there are results returned from the controller - table get's refreshed.

But when a user inputs a search with a string that doesn't yield any results (empty list) the table does not refresh/clear, but the rows of the last (successful) query are still shown.

How to show empty table (no rows) when an empty list is returned from the controller?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your data is returned, but you can access info about your returned object like this:

```
$("#sectionList").load(url, function(response, status, xhr) {

});
```

This way you can test the 'response' variable and act accordingly.  For example if you were sending back a json object you do something like:

```
$("#sectionList").load(url, function(response, status, xhr) {
   if(response.length === 0)
        $("#sectionList").html("No results");
   });
});
```

Comment: I checked my code that returns the model and for the list i'm using a PaginatedList (helper) that has a CreateAsync method like:

public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            var count = await source.CountAsync();
            var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
            return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
        }
and this fails when source is empty

Comment: @TheMixy - can you post what the response looks like as captured in the F12 dev tools?  When you say it fails when empty, does it fail at the server, or the client?

Comment: PaginatedList helper I copied from this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Comment: var item... (as in my code in the first comment) fails. The error is too long for posting in comments, but i think one relevant part may be:

Comment: OFFSET @__p_2 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_3 ROWS ONLY
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Interactive.Async.dll
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Error: An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Backend.Infrastructure.ApplicationDbContext'.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The offset specified in a OFFSET clause may not be negative.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was in the PaginatedList I was using from this MS guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-2.0

It's CreateAsync method returns an error when the data source is an empty result set.

So, I just added a check in my controller before sending the model to my view like this:

```cs
if(result.Count() == 0)
            {
                model.Kontakti = new PaginatedList<KontaktiDetailModel>(result.ToList(), 0, 0, pageSize);
            }
            else
            {
                model.Kontakti = await PaginatedList<KontaktiDetailModel>.CreateAsync(result.AsNoTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize);
            }
```

Now, I get an empty table when there are no results matching the users search.